# mvc3 model does not contain definition for GetEnumerator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

This is the controller. 
what I need is to access the IList named model in the view. I want to display Barcode and ImageUrl.

```
using BezoekerSysteem.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BezoekerSysteem.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

public ActionResult PrintPage()
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("");
                string query = "select * From visitors";
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
                sda.Fill(dt);
                con.Close();
                IList<VisitorResponse> model = new List<VisitorResponse>();
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var p = dt.Rows[i]["BarCodeImage"];
                    model.Add(new VisitorResponse()
                    {
                        Barcode = dt.Rows[i]["Barcode"].ToString(),
                        ImageUrl = dt.Rows[i]["BarCodeImage"] != null ? "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])dt.Rows[i]["BarCodeImage"]) : ""
                    });
                }
                return View(model);
            }
}
```

**This is the model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace BezoekerSysteem.Models
{
    public class VisitorResponse
    {
        public byte[] BarcodeImage      { get; set; }
        public string Barcode           { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl          { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is what I tryed.

```
@model BezoekerSysteem.Models.VisitorResponse

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
            <div>
            @foreach (var item in Model) {
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Barcode) <br />

                  <img src="@item.ImageUrl"/>
                }    
            </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

error message:

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'BezoekerSysteem.Models.VisitorResponse' because 'BezoekerSysteem.Models.VisitorResponse' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

I also tryed to change this.

```
@model BezoekerSysteem.Models.VisitorResponse
```

In to this.

```
@model IEnumerable<BezoekerSysteem.Models.VisitorResponse>
```

Then I got no errors in visual studio but when I run it I get an error in my browser

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'BezoekerSysteem.Models.VisitorResponse', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BezoekerSysteem.Models.VisitorResponse]'.
```

Comment: Your `PrintPage()` method defines your model as a collection `IList<VisitorResponse> model = new List<VisitorResponse>();` which you pass to the view so it needs to be `@model IEnumerable<BezoekerSysteem.Models.VisitorResponse>`. The error in the browser makes no sense. Are you sure this is the correct code?

Comment: thanks for the answer. your answer did remind me of something. I have a other ViewResult Registrationform that return view("PrintPage",visitorResponse); if posted. I think thats why I get the error because it cant access the code that is in the ActionResult PrintPage

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would read up on Entity Framework for data-access; it will make your life A LOT easier.

As your question:
You are trying to loop over an object which isn't possible. That is what your first error was about.
So changing the @model was a good thing.

The second error is strange, make sure you stop debugging, rebuild and rerun when trying again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did the rebuild and clean solution but I still get that second error

Comment: With @model IList<BezoekerSysteem.Models.VisitorResponse>?
edit: also, check in your controller that the model you return is actually filled

Answer (score 0):

Change the model in your view as given in below.
IList can not accept the IEnumerable, But IEnumurable accepts the Ilist 
So try the below code

```
@model List<BezoekerSysteem.Models.VisitorResponse>
```

Comment: I fixed the problem. I had 2 controllers return the view(); so change one return to return RedirectToAction("PrintPage", "Home"); that worked. but thanks for helping